# How to condition the mounting of a component to data from that component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have quite a bit of Vue3 components that depend on external data (typically, a `fetch` to an API, or asynchronous data from a bus).

The effect is that, upon mounting of the component, some of the operations using reactive data fail with errors similar to

```
Cannot read property 'weather' of undefined
```

This is normal, the reactive data has not been retrieved yet and everything is fixed once I get it. It just leaves aesthetically unpleasant errors in the console.

I would like to find a way to wait with whatever happens in `setup()` until the data I need is retrieved (the retrieval happens *within* the component, so I cannot use a `v-if` on the parent).

Is there a way to gracefully handle such cases?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing more of your code but you can check whether your data has loaded and write a v-if in your component rather than the parent  <div  v-if='dataLoaded || item !== undefined'>

Comment: @RodP: but this will not help with operations within `setup()`, right? I could have no elements in `<template>` and `setup()` would still be executed

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you were just worried about display, I should have read your Q more carefully.  I think we need more code.

Comment: If I understand the question right async-await will solve the issue.
-> let data = await fetchLogic();
->use data
Anyways code will help understand he issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is use case for [suspense](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/suspense.html#introduction).

As long as `<suspense>` is used in parent component, a child can be asynchronous and  fetch initial data before mount:

```
async setup() {
  const initialData = await ...;
  const data = reactive(initialData);
  return { data };
}
```

Otherwise a child needs safeguards that prevent non-existent properties from being accessed.

With generic fetch hook that has `isLoading` state:

```
<div v-if="isLoading">
  Loading...
</div>
<div v-else>
  {{data.foo}}
</div>
```

With conditional property access:

```
<div>
  {{data?.foo}}
</div>
```

Or anywhere in between, depending on the requirements on how non-loaded data should be represented in view.